# How to prevent the execution of functions twice for the current user?

Tags: php, wordpress

It is necessary for me that function was fulfilled only 1 time for one user.
if you try again, nothing would happen.
If another user logs in, the function will be executed for him but only once.
and so on for all other users.
It is necessary that the check be repeated on each page separately. 
And did not go to the other pages in single.php

my function

```
if( current_user_can('author') || current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ){  
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, 'post_count', true);
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, 'post_count', $count);
    echo $count.;
}
```

}

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you are talking about a permanent change and do not wish to change the status of something in the future, create a column in your database that relates to your user to inform your program that something was already executed/changed.

If persistence is not a problem and you just wish to block it from doing it again in the next foreseeable future, just create a session for that user with a variable that also informs your program that something was executed/changed,

Comment: But how then to make it automatically work on each page separately?

Comment: That will depend which approach you are adopting. After you choose and share some code I can help more :)

Comment: I wrote the code above. the function with updating each page increases the number by one and works for each page separately. I only need to force the function to run once for each user separately. this is necessary in order to avoid cheating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is useful to someone, this is the code whereby the function can be disabled twice.

```
function function_views($postID) {  
    if( current_user_can('author') || current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ){ 
   $user_id_views_check = get_current_user_id(); 
   $check_views = get_user_meta( $user_id_views_check, 'meta_check_views', true ); 
   if ( !$check_views || !isset($check_views[$postID]) ){   //
    $check_views[$postID] = 1;
    update_user_meta($user_id_views_check, 'meta_check_views', $check_views);
    echo 'TEST views';  
    $number_views = get_post_meta($postID, 'views_registration', true);
    $number_views++;
    update_post_meta($postID, 'views_registration', $number_views);
    }}}
```

Works only for registered users. inserted into file functions.php

To display the result is used

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
$number_views = get_post_meta($postID, 'views_registration', true);
echo $number_views.' Views';
}
```

In order to display insert it

```
<?php function_views(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

to count and

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

for withdrawal